# What is Meaning of mean_score_time in scikit-learn Grid Search Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am a bit confused with the meaning of `mean_score_time` in [GridSearch](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

For the `mean_fit_time` it's clear that it's the average time of training between different folds.
But in case of `mean_score_time` I don't know whether it's the time taken by each `Cross-Validation` set to be classified or what?

I tried to compute the time for the test set

```
start = time.time()
y_tst_pred = estimator.predict(X_test)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

and the results came much smaller although the test set is larger and should give larger time.

> To avoid confusion: My question has two main parts:

1 - What is the `mean_score_time`.. I know its logical to assume that it is the mean classification time across different folds ... but my second part is the reason for confusion.

2 - Assuming that `mean_score_time` is the time needed for evaluation. why the time used for classifying the test set (test set approx = 550 sample) is lower than the `mean_score_time` (cross validation approx = 440).. `mean_score_time`=56 ms and the time measured in clustering the test set = 35 ms.

P.s. Some of the answers suggest `mean_score_time` contains classification and scoring time (comparing the predicted results and labels) but none of the documentations say something like this.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself in the question and in the comments of the below answer. Is your test set prediction larger or smaller? Without the actual data, its hard to say anything.

Comment: The test set is larger than the cross validation set (test set approx = 550 and cross validation approx = 440) and the value of "mean_score_time "=56 ms and the time measured in clustering the test set = 35 ms.

Comment: and please tell me the contradiction source to fix it :)

Comment: In the answer below you commented `"if this is the prediction time, why the prediction time of the test set is **much larger **"`.

Comment: And the score is higher maybe because you are only predicting the values, whereas grid-search is predicting and then scoring also. And what do you mean by cross-validation set?

Comment: Grid search splits the data into multiple folds where each fold is tested against the classifier trained from the other folds... the cross validation set is each set used for validation round to be able to choose the best configuration for the classifier. I didn't separate it manually its done automatically by the grid. did this answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

`GridSearchCV.cv_results_` includes timing results for scoring and fitting each parameter fold.  `mean_score_time` is the average amount of time across all cv-folds for each set of parameters you defined in your parameter grid that it takes to score the data in each fold.

Behind the scenes `sklearn` is only explicitly measuring how long the fitting procedure takes then subtracts that `fit_time` from the total time the process took for each fold where the difference is considered the `score_time`.

Comment: do you mean that the mean_score_time is not the prediction time.. and I have to measure the prediction time myself ?

Comment: `mean_score_time` is the average prediction time for each set of parameters across all the folds.  If you have 10 folds in your `CV` then `mean_score_time` will be the average prediction time across the 10 folds.  There is obviously some variation across each fold where you can use `std_score_time` to get an idea for how those values vary around that mean value.

Comment: if this is the prediction time, why the prediction time of the test set is **much larger **

Comment: There are a lot of reasons that could be the case... if the test set is larger than the size of the data in each fold it could be larger.  Would also want to validate you're looking at the correct `mean_score_time` in `cv_results_` to make sure it's for the best parameters.  Without context around the specific problem you're facing it's difficult to diagnose why that would be happening.